# Navigation responsiveness problems

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm having issues with my navigation bar. My aim is to have a normal horizontal navbar on desktop and then a collapsible navbar on mobile, I have that but 1 thing is wrong. I cant hide the links and then show them once the toggle button has been clicked, any help?

Codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/RRGvYV

HTML:

```
    <div class="navigation-group">
        <div class="container">
        <div class="navigation-top">    
        <a class="nav-name">Architect</a>
        <button class="nav-toggle" id="nav-toggle">A</button>
        </div>    
            <nav role="navigation" class="collapase navigation-bar">
                <ul class="nav">
                    <li><a href="#">Examples</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Download</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">FAQ</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
                <ul class="nav nav-right">
                    <li><a href="#">Extra</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Extra</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </div>
```

CSS (SASS):

```
@media (min-width : 768px)
    .navigation-bar
        list-style-type: none

        ul
            float: left

        li
            float: left

        &:before, &:after
            display: table
            content: ""   
    .nav-right
        float: right !important   
    .navigation-top
        width: auto !important
        padding: 5px 20px
        float: left
        line-height: 40px  
    .nav-toggle
        display: none !important   

.open
    display: block!important

.collapase
    display: none

.navigation-top
    width: 100%
    padding: 5px 20px
    float: left
    line-height: 40px 
    border-bottom: solid 1px #E5E5E5
.nav-name
    font-weight: bold
    float: left
.navigation-group
    min-height: 50px
    background-color: #fff
    &:before, &:after
        display: table
        content: ""      


.navigation-bar  

    li
        position: relative
        display: block
        line-height: 40px

    a
        display: block
        color: #000
        text-align: center
        padding: 5px 20px
        font-weight: bold
        text-decoration: none     

    &:before, &:after
        display: table
        content: ""

.navigation-name
    float: left
    padding: 10px 20px
    font-size: 18px
    text-decoration: none
    font-weight: bold
    color: red

.nav-toggle
    display: block
    font-size: 34px
    font-weight: bold
    position: relative
    float: right
    padding: 6px 12px
    margin-top: 0px
    margin-right: 15px
    margin-bottom: 0px
    background-color: transparent
    background-image: none
    border: 1px solid transparent
    border-radius: 4px
    cursor: pointer
    outline: none
```

jQuery:

```
$( "#nav-toggle" ).click(function(){
   $( ".navigation-bar" ).toggle();
    });
```

Im looking for a system like bootstraps.

Comment: Have you forgotten to include jQuery? it is not present in the codepen. Besides that you should consider using `;` and brackets for you CSS for consistency and overview. And why not use Bootstrap..?

Answer (score 0):

1. Add `jquery.min.js` to your codepen.
2. Use `$( "nav.navigation-bar" ).toggleClass("open");`
   instead of `$( ".navigation-bar" ).toggle();`
3. When the menu is expanded, it covers the toggle-button. Because of this the button becomes inaccessible. You can solve the issue by adding the `z-index: 20;` property to the `.nav-toggle` class.

Check the result: http://codepen.io/glebkema/pen/BzLbve

Answer (score -1):

Only thing I updated is the use of jquery in your codepen. That is all, hope that helps you. See codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/BzLMgx. Besides, you should add brackets and CSS syntax. Added external `https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js` code. Also I have edited the `z-index` to 20 of the button, it used to be under the layer of the first link in the dropdown (Example link)

Comment: Nothing has changed?

Comment: Sorry I updated the codepen, now used the 'A' button as click event.

Comment: Did this help you @Zoid?